# MongoDB check if array is inside an array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I wanted to count the number of entries in my collection, but looks like my code doesn't work.

```
var count = LeavesCollection.find({ $and:[
        {user_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}},
        {associate_tower: {$in: Meteor.user().profile.tower}},
        {leaves_approval_status: {$not: {$ne: 'Pre-Approved'}}}
    ]}).count();
```

If I remove the second query (`associate_tower`), the count works fine. The Associate tower is an array (e.g. ["Support"] ) and the `Meteor.user().profile.tower` is also an Array (e.g. ["Support", QAS, PPD] )

How can I achieve the right count?

Comment: if the 'associate_tower' is a String, it works fine, but I need it inside an array.

Comment: FYI - you shouldn't need the `$and:` as *and* is assumed for multi-key queries. The `$not: {$ne:` is also a bit odd, seems like a double negative.

Comment: According to [Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array), `$in` when evaluating two arrays should return docs where any element of array1 is in array2.

Comment: If you change `associate_tower` to a String, it will also work fine. I don't know if that helps you

Comment: @MichelFloyd, $eq is not supported by minimongo, so $not: {$ne: is one alternative for that.

Comment: Checking equality doesn't require an operator, just use `{leaves_approval_status: 'Pre-Approved'}`

Comment: I see but the problem is not the leaves `{leaves_approval_status: {$not: {$ne: 'Pre-Approved'}}}`, but rather this one `{associate_tower: {$in: Meteor.user().profile.tower}}`